# Reading multiple sources of data to datatable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I have the following code which reads data from a file and from an SQL table to a datatable which displays data in a gridview.

I am having issues with the display of data. Each source is read to a new line in the datatable. I would like for it to be all on one line. Is the issue that I have three if statements reading into datable? If so how can I fix this issue?

Note: The values are on different lines in the file and may occur more than once in the file

The table output looks as follows:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

Many thanks,
Erica

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Path As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Path)
    Dim lines As List(Of String) = IO.File.ReadLines(Path).ToList
    Dim idx As Integer = 0
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    dt.Columns.Add("Year")
    dt.Columns.Add("Cost")

    Do While idx < lines.Count - 1

        Dim line As String = lines(idx)

        '--YEAR
        If line.Substring(11, 2) = "14" Then

            Dim Year = "20" & line.Substring(16, 6).ToString()
            Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow

            R("Year") = Year
            dt.Rows.Add(R)

        End If

        '--Cost
        If line.Substring(5, 2) = "50" Then


            Dim Cost As Decimal = (line.Substring(75, 4) & "." & line.Substring(80, 2))

            '-- ID FROM FILE
            Dim ID As String = (line.Substring(18, 3))

            Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            R("Cost") = Cost
            dt.Rows.Add(R)

            Dim conConn As New SqlConnection
            Dim comComm As SqlCommand = Nothing
            conConn = New SqlConnection(Con)

            '--GET NAME FROM DATABASE
            comComm = New SqlCommand
            With comComm
                .Connection = conConn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = "SELECT NAME FROM [TEST].[dbo].[tblTest] WHERE ID = @ID"
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)

                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(comComm)
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                End Using

            End With
        End If

        DataGridView1.Visible = True
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        idx += 1

    Loop


End Sub
```

***Updated Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are adding a row dt.rows.add(R) for each value, what you want to do is create an array containing the values you want on a single row and then add that row.  Heres an example.

```
    Dim CellOne as string
    Dim CellTwo as string
    Dim CellThree as string
    Dim RowContents() as String

    CellOne = getCellOneVal(etc, etc)
    CellTwo = Convert.ToString(getCellTwoVal())
    CellThree = getCellThreeVal(etc, etc)
    
    RowContents = {CellOne, CellTwo, CellThree}
    dt.rows.add(RowContents)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I understand the concept of trying to create an array however I have two if statements and also an SQL statement so I am unsure how to apply this alternatively from the way I have above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will fully fix the issue, as it's not clear whether the values are on one line or different lines. Sharing an example file with a record or two would help us. However, this might do a little better, and there are a number of meaningful improvements in this code even if it doesn't fully fix things:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Path As String = TextBox1.Text
    ' Improve memory use by only keeping one line in memory at a time
    Dim lines As IEnumerable(Of String) = IO.File.ReadLines(Path)

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Year")
    dt.Columns.Add("Cost")
    dt.Columns.Add("Name") ' Define ALL of the columns up front

    For Each line As String in lines
        Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

        ' Year 
        If line.Substring(11, 2) = "14" Then
           R("Year") = "20" & line.Substring(16, 6)
        End If

        ' Cost
        If line.Substring(5, 2) = "50" Then
           R("Cost") = CDec(line.Substring(75, 4) & "." & line.Substring(80, 2))
        End If

        ' ID => Name
        Dim ID As String = line.Substring(18, 3)
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT NAME FROM [TEST].[dbo].[tblTest] WHERE ID = @ID"
        ' Using block is better to ensure the connection is closed/disposed properly
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(Con), 
              cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL)

            ' AddWithValue() can have HUGE performance issues in the wrong circumstances
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NChar, 3).Value = ID
            cn.Open()
            ' ExecuteScalar() is FAR more efficient if you only need one value
            R("Name") = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        End Using
        
        ' Only create and add one row per loop iteration
        dt.Rows.Add(R)
    Next line

    ' Don't bind the grid until after we've finished reading the file
    DataGridView1.Visible = True
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

I'm also tempted to factor out the code to parse one line to it's own method (say: `ParseLine()`) that accepts a string and returns a tuple, class, or dictionary.

That would let you simlify the button click event down to something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Year")
    dt.Columns.Add("Cost")
    dt.Columns.Add("Name") 

    ' Assumes Option Infer
    For Each record In IO.File.ReadLines(TextBox1.Text).
            Select(Function(line) ParseLine(line))

        Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        R("Year") = record("Year") 'This will look a little different depending on class vs dictionary vs tuple
        R("Cost") = record("Cost")
        R("Name") = record("Name")
 
        dt.Rows.Add(R)
    Next

    DataGridView1.Visible = True
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Public Function ParseLine(line As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim result As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    ' Year 
    If line.Substring(11, 2) = "14" Then
         result("Year") = "20" & line.Substring(16, 6)
    End If

    ' Cost
    If line.Substring(5, 2) = "50" Then
        result("Cost") = line.Substring(75, 4) & "." & line.Substring(80, 2)
    End If

    ' ID => Name
    Dim ID As String = line.Substring(18, 3)
    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT NAME FROM [TEST].[dbo].[tblTest] WHERE ID = @ID"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection(Con), 
          cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NChar, 3).Value = ID
        cn.Open()
        result("Name") = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    End Using

    Return result
End Function
```

---

I'm still having to guess about how the file actually works, but comments indicate this might do better:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Path As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim lines As IEnumerable(Of String) = IO.File.ReadLines(Path)

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Year")
    dt.Columns.Add("Cost")
    dt.Columns.Add("Name") ' Define ALL of the columns up front
  
    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT NAME FROM [TEST].[dbo].[tblTest] WHERE ID = @ID"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(Con), 
          cmd As New SQlCommand(SQL, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbtype.NChar, 3)  
        cn.Open()

        Dim keepGoing As Boolean = lines.MoveNext() ' start the enumerable
        While keepGoing
        
            Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
            Dim curID As String = lines.Current.Substring(18,3)
            Dim lineID As String = curID

            ' Name
            cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = curID
            R("Name") = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            
            While curID = lineID AndAlso keepGoing
                
                ' Year
                If lines.Current.Substring(11, 2) = "14" Then
                    R("Year") = "20" & lines.Current.Substring(16, 6)
                End If

                ' Cost
                If lines.Current.Substring(5, 2) = "50" Then
                    R("Cost") = lines.Current.Substring(75, 4) & "." & lines.Current.Substring(80, 2)
                End If
     
                keepGoing = lines.MoveNext()
                lineID = lines.Current.Substring(18,3)
            End While

            dt.Rows.Add(R)
        End While
    End Using

    ' Don't bind the grid until after we've finished reading the file
    DataGridView1.Visible = True
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Joel, Thank you for taking the time to write out all that great code. To clarify the values are on multiple lines and may occur multiple times throughout the file. I have run your code and unfortunately, the output is still on multiple lines. The output looks like the image I have added to the original question (***Updated output). The name appears multiple times. This could be because it appears multiple times throughout the file on different lines. Is there a way to just display the first so I achieve the results in one line? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Also what is the alternative to ExecuteScalar() as I could need more than one value

Comment: If the data is spread over multiple lines, we'll need a sample of the file.

Comment: @Martha Maybe the new attempt at the bottom. It uses a control/break loop structure, but I'm still having to guess about when to break to the next record.

Comment: I have edited your above code and I am getting the cost and name in the same row. However, I want to select more than one item in the SQL statement. is there a suitable alternative to cmd.ExecuteScalar() as you suggested it is efficient for one value. so I am curious how I can amend my code to be efficient for multiple values. Also thank you for your help I am always keep to learn to be better